# Toggle visibility between multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find the simplest JS solution, preferably jQuery, to accomplish the following:  I have a number of divs, all with the same class, that I want to simply toggle visibility of each, one at a time.

```
<a href="#" id="toggle-trigger">Toggle Div Visibility</a>    
<div class="slide" id="slide-one"></div>
<div class="slide" id="slide-two"></div>
<div class="slide" id="slide-three"></div>
<div class="slide" id="slide-four"></div>
<div class="slide" id="slide-five"></div>
```

The first div, is by default, always visible via CSS.

```
.slide{
display:none;
}
#slide-one{
display:block;
}
```

I've been unable to find anything other than just toggling between two elements, not multiple items.  Please let me know if I can find the answer elsewhere.  Thanks

Comment: can you explain what is the behavior you expect to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
  ​$(​'#toggle-trigger')​​​​​​​​​​.click(function()
  {
    var $Current = $('.slide:visible');
    var $Slides = $('.slide');
    var $Next = $Current.next();
    if ($Next.length == 0) $Next = $Slides.first();
    $Slides.hide();
    $Next.show();
  });
```

I made a JSFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/uxqBx/

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but why are you adding a dollar sign to you variable names?

Comment: I don't agree here because your slides have to be consecutives for this to work. you should add a selector to your next()

Comment: Am I the only one getting a blank when the loop restarts?

Answer (score 1):

Even if Wivlaro made an answer, here is different way, using class for active element instead of `:visible` pseudo-selector.

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHRWr/)

Comment: yeah, I do actually prefer this version.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.slide').each(function(){
    $(this).show().prev().hide();
});
```

Or if you want to time it:

```
$('.slide').each(function(i){
    var elt = this;
    setTimeout(function(){$(elt).show().prev().hide()},i*1000);
});
```

***wrong answer***

---

now as a slideshow :

```
var current;
$(function(){
     current = $('.slide').first();
     SetInterval(function(){
         var next = $(current).next('.slide');
         if(next.length == 0)
                 current = $('.slide').first();
         $(current).hide();
         $(next).show();
     },1000);
```

EDIT: added toggling, I thought you wanted the div to show one after another but keeping the visibility. Now it should toggle.

Comment: Could you add a delay to the first code, to make similar to second.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, something went wrong, I post it late. - http://jsfiddle.net/ZEBza/

```
$("#toggle-trigger").click(function() {
    var opened="";
    $(".slide").each(function(i, el) {
      console.log(opened);
      var pass = true;
      if(opened!="")
      {
         $(el).css("display", "block");
         opened = "";
         pass = false;
      }
      if($(el).css("display")=="block" && pass)
      {
         opened = $(el).attr("id");
         $(el).css("display", "none");
      }
    });
  if(opened!="")
  {
      $(".slide:first").css("display", "block");
  }
});
```